# How to display the CDK table without the same customer ID Angular

Tags: angular

I have a cdk table to display the data, however I have some duplicated data, and 
the dataSource like this

```
[
{customerID:"56789", name: "foo", mobile: "123456"},
{customerID:"56789", name: "foo", mobile: "123456"},
{customerID:"12345", name: "foo", mobile: "123456"},
{customerID:"12345", name: "foo", mobile: "123456"},
{customerID:"45678", name: "foo", mobile: "123456"}
]
```

Now I want to hide the columns with the same customerID. So instead of showing 5 records in the list, showing only 3 record.
Any condition I could apply for the mdTable, or md-cell to achieve that? 
Thank you for helping.

Comment: You can filter data before providing data source to the table.

Comment: And for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a pipe to filter data, something like:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filterId',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterValue implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[]): any {
  const uniqueArr = [];
  const ids = items.map((value) => value.customerID);
  items.map((value, index) => {
    if(ids.indexOf(value.customerID) !== index) {
      // duplicate value, delete or do whatever you want to
      delete value.customerID
      uniqueArr.push(value)
    } else {
      uniqueArr.push(value)
    }
  })
  return uniqueArr;
}
```

}

and in your view:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ArrayVariable | filterId">
<div *ngIf="item.customerID">
```